# Помогите с std::transform с++

Tags: c++

Вот дан код:

```
void SaveChangesToFile(Dictionary const& dictionary, string const& dictionaryFileName)
    {
        ofstream dictionaryFile(dictionaryFileName);
        for (auto translation : dictionary)
        {
            dictionaryFile << translation.first << "|" << translation.second << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно заменить в коде на `std::transform`?

Comment: Можно заменить цикл for на основе диапазона.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вывод в поток нужно оформить в виде оператора `<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Translation& tr){
    os << translation.first << "|" << translation.second;
    return os;
}
```

Я не знаю какого типа у вас объект translation, поэтому оставляю это на вашей совести.

Теперь тело вашей функции выглядит так:

```
void SaveChangesToFile(Dictionary const& dictionary, string const& dictionaryFileName){
    ofstream dictionaryFile(dictionaryFileName);
    for (auto translation : dictionary){
        dictionaryFile << translation << "\n";
    }
}
```

В этот момент я понял, что отвечаю не совсем на ваш вопрос, потому что в итоге код примет такой вид:

```
void SaveChangesToFile(Dictionary const& dictionary, string const& dictionaryFileName){
    ofstream dictionaryFile(dictionaryFileName);
    std::copy(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Translation>(dictionaryFile, "\n"));
}
```

Если вас устроит решение с помощью `std::copy`, то можете на этом остановиться. Если вам кровь из носу нужен `std::transform`, то пойдем по другому пути.

Напишем функтор, который будет преобразовывать объект `translation` в строку:

```
struct ToString{
    std::stringstream ss;
    inline std::string operator()(const Translation &tr) const{
        ss << translation.first << "|" << translation.second;
        return ss.str();
    }
};
```

Опять же, я не знаю что за тип Translation. Может можно было обойтись и без `std::stringstream`.
Теперь можно воспользоваться `std::transform`:

```
void SaveChangesToFile(Dictionary const& dictionary, string const& dictionaryFileName){
    ofstream dictionaryFile(dictionaryFileName);
    std::transform(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(dictionaryFile, "\n"), ToString());
}
```

**Подведем итоги.**
 Полный вариант с `std::copy` выглядит так:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Translation& tr){
    os << translation.first << "|" << translation.second;
    return os;
}
void SaveChangesToFile(Dictionary const& dictionary, string const& dictionaryFileName){
    ofstream dictionaryFile(dictionaryFileName);
    std::copy(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Translation>(dictionaryFile, "\n"));
}
```

Полный вариант с `std::std::transform` выглядит так:

```
struct ToString{
    std::stringstream ss;
    inline std::string operator()(const Translation &tr) const{
        ss << translation.first << "|" << translation.second;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

void SaveChangesToFile(Dictionary const& dictionary, string const& dictionaryFileName){
    ofstream dictionaryFile(dictionaryFileName);
    std::transform(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(dictionaryFile, "\n"), ToString());
}
```

На мой взгляд код с `std::copy` получился лучше. Во-первых он короче, а во вторых нет ненужного преобразования `translation` в строку.

Comment: огромное спасибо, вы меня очень сильно выручили.